# What is the proper way to translate Soil Yard, Bulk Yard & Bulk Soil Yard to Spanish

Tags: traducción, inglés

What is the proper way to translate Soil Yard, Bulk Yard & Bulk Soil Yard to Spanish?

I'm creating multiple display names for Apple Maps in different languages and couldn't figure out which translation was appropriate.

- Soil Yard
- Bulk Yard
- Bulk Soil Yard

Comment: Welcome to [spanish.se]! Please share your research; which translations have you found so far? This will help us in providing you with a good answer.

Comment: You  need to provide **more context. These are specialized terms**. I don't even know them in English. And I do  lot of technical work. Something tells me those terms are not right in English. I think you mean: yard soil, bulk yard soil. And bulk yard does not exist.

Comment: So, have you just vamoosed?

Comment: It's in regards to dirt and soil sold in large quantities for growing vegetables, herbs, grass, Texas native plants, trees & acid loving plants like roses and berries

Comment: You need to define each one. The only ones that make sense are: yard soil AND yard soil in bulk. And frankly, I don't get how they relate to large quantifies. soil in large quantities is purchased in tons.

Answer (score 1):

El lugar donde se vende todo tipo de elemento relacionado con el Jardin es *vivero*.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Yard, Generally, these sites sell everything needed for landscaping and renovating gardens, from soil for plants to various types of stones and outdoor decorations.

These shops are not very common in Spanish-speaking countries, although there are some specialised shops, generally everything related to plants (soil, fertilisers, substrates, grass...) is bought in places called Viveros.

Everything related to sand, gravel, stones of different sizes, coverings and supports for garden paths are bought in shops of construction materials,  usually places like "Leroy-Merlin" / "Home Depot" (or similar) sell this kind of things.

Comment: bulk yard? Show me a definition and an example.